# bootstrap url validation using regex for complete url

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am trying to validate my url field using bootstap validator

here is how my input html looks like

problem is it shows http://www.google as valid

i want it to be shown valid only when user types complete url with extension ie only when one types http://www.google.com

anyone faced and fixed similar issue?

Comment: <input type="url" maxlength="50" data-bv-trigger="blur" data-bv-field="urlCompany" name="urlCompany" class="form-control input-sm" id="urlCompany" placeholder="http://www.yourcompany.com/">

Comment: Where is your regex?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google is valid URL (2nd level domain name).

There is a list of valid examples: http://formvalidation.io/validators/uri/